# @@IDENTITY and Concurrence

Tags: sql, multithreading, identity

Say I have a table **TableA** whose primary key is marked as `IDENTITY`, and that I execute the following two statements in a stored procedure

```
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
SET @SomeVariable = @@IDENTITY
```

in order that `@SomeVariable` stores the primary key of the just-added value. If another client executes the same insert between the execution of the statements above, is it possible that `@@IDENTITY` and thus `@SomeVariable` stores the wrong (most recent) value?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

`@@IDENTITY` is for *your* connection  only (not global) so you should get the last IDENTITY value that happened on your connection. However, this could be from a different scope, such as a trigger.

This is why [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) is best practice: it is for the scope with the INSERT and does not take into account triggers etc

For a truly global, non-concurrent and frankly idiotic solution it's [`IDENT_CURRENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx). This will be affected by everyone who connect and writes to the table.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you mean by another client. @@IDENTITY returns the last identity value produced on a connection / session (regardless of table or scope of the command).

So if your clients do not share the connection the answer is no. If they share the connection (I don't think so because it will have many other problems) the answer is yes.